# AS/400 licensing error

Tags: .net, db2

I need to create a standalone application connecting to AS/400 system and read data from a table.

Actually I have "database name", "hostname", "user" and "password" of AS/400.

I have downloaded and installed from IBM website IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER for ODBC. I have configured a DSN using data above.

When from source administration I try to connect I get the following message:

> SQL1598N An Attemp to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem. SQLSTATE=42968

Now I don't know what I can do. Do I have to purchase something? Is there a free solution to connect to AS/400 (it is my first time and I really don't know)?

AS/400 is from another company, do they have to give me something to allow me connecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [need a special license](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0024162.html) to be able to connect to an IBM i system (formerly known as AS/400). At a minimum, you will need [IBM i Access software](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/), which includes the ODBC driver and the required license. See if the organization that owns the server can provide you with a copy.

They also may be able to set up a DB2 Connect server, which will serve as a gateway to the i system. You will use the ODBC driver that you already have, without requiring an extra license, to connect to that gateway.